# EmberJS Sending a property to another controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to pass back a property to use in a view on another route. For exmaple, my `contact/user/new` controller is doing the following:

```
var newContact = this.get('store').createRecord('contact', contactData);
  newContact.save().then((contact) => {
    this.transitionToRoute('contacts');
    this.set('successMessage', 'You have successfully created a new contact!');
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    response.errors.forEach((error) => {
      this.set('errorMessages', error.message);
    });
  });
```

Everything works for me except that `successMessage` line.

```
this.set('successMessage', 'You have successfully created a new contact!');
```

I'd like to have it accessible on the `customers` template so I could do something like:

```
{{#if successMessage}}
  <div class="success-message">
    {{successMessage}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: You should send an action and catch it from the application route, have the notification popup be in the application route

Answer (score 1):

You can declare dependencies between controllers using the [`needs`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) attribute.

So you have to add this in your controller where you create your record :

```
needs: 'customers'   // Assuming you have a CustomersController somewhere
```

And you would set the message in your desired controller by doing :

```
this.set('controllers.customers.successMessage', 'Fancy message');
```

Comment: I've tried this as well. I added this line to my controller:

    needs: 'customers/index' then tried this.set('controllers.customers/index.successMessage', 'Fancy message');

Comment: You need to set the name of the controller in the `needs`, not the route. So it should be `customers`, not `customers/index`.